# API to check if BlackBerry device is password-protected

Tags: java, blackberry

Is there an API to check if the device is currently password-protected?

I can only allow caching server login keys on the device if the device itself is password protected (recommending IT policy to the BES admins is not enough for the customer). Somehow I cannot find the suitable API call(s), looking up and down through the documentation and APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

`net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo.isPasswordEnabled()`